# Expresión regular para mantener sólo la primera palabra de la línea, seguida por una coma

Tags: regex, notepad++

**Situación:**

Tengo un archivo con datos que tienen el siguiente formato:

```
ID       FLOAT(20),
NAME     VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
TRIBUTE  VARCHAR2(4 BYTE),
GOLD     VARCHAR2(2 BYTE),
```

voy a aplicar una Expresión regular para buscar y remplazar los datos por esta salida (Primera palabra de la línea, seguida por una coma):

```
ID,
NAME,
TRIBUTE,
GOLD,
```

**Solución en Microsoft Word**

La operación en Microsoft Word es esta:

Buscar: `<(??*) (*?,)`

Remplazar: `\1,`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Problema**

Ahora quiero obtener la misma salida en Notepad++, pero aún no logro conseguirlo.

**Actualizaciones Solución en Notepad++:**

Leyendo http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions y ensayando, he dedicido las siguientes equivalencias

```
Busqueda                            |   Word    |   Notepad++   |
------------------------------------+-----------+---------------|
Principio de línea                  |     <     |       ^       |
Cómodin un caracterer cualquiera    |     ?     |      .?       |
Cómodin uno o muchos caracterers    |     *     |      .*       |
Guardar búsqueda                    |    ()     |       ()      |
Busquedad Guardada                  |    /#     |       /#      |
```

una posible solución seria realizar dos busquedas,

**Primera Busqueda**

Buscar: `^(.?.?.*)  (.*),`

Remplazar: `\1,`

**Segunda Busqueda**

Buscar:

Remplazar:

(Buscar "espacio" y remplazar por "nada")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Esto debería hacer el truco para ti:

```
^(\S+).*$
```

Reemplazar con:

```
$1,
```

[Ver la expresión regular](http://bit.ly/1JXFjtj)

Comment: +1 Tambien funciona en Sublime Text